# How to read a file and write it entirely to several text files using Python?

Tags: python, file, read-write

I want to load/read a text file and write it to two other text files "entirely". I will write other different data to the following of these two files later.
The problem is that the loaded file is only written to the first file, and no data from that loaded file is written to the second file.

The code I am using:

```
fin = open("File_Read", 'r')
fout1 = open("File_Write1", 'w')
fout2 = open("File_Write2", 'w')

fout1.write(fin.read())
fout2.write(fin.read())   #Nothing is written here!

fin.close()  
fout1.close()
fout2.close()
```

What is happening and what is the solution?
I prefer using *open* instead of *with open*.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the `fin.read()` reads all the lines, the next `fin.read()` will continue from where the previous `.read()` ended (which is the last line). To solve this, I would simply go for:

```
text_fin = fin.read()
fout1.write(text_fin)
fout2.write(text_fin)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fin = open("test.txt", 'r')
data = fin.read()
fin.close()  

fout1 = open("test2.txt", 'w')
fout1.write(data)
fout1.close()

fout2 = open("test3.txt", 'w')
fout2.write(data)
fout2.close()
```

N.B. `with open` is the safest and best way but at least you need to close the file as soon as there are not needed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can try iterating through your original file line by line and appending it to both the files. You are running into the problem because file.write() method takes string argument.

```
fin = open("File_Read",'r')
fout1 = open("File_Write1",'a')   #append permissions for line-by-line writing
fout2 = open("File_Write2",'a')   #append permissions for line-by-line writing
for lines in fin:
    fout1.write(lines)
    fout2.write(lines)

fin.close()
fout1.close()
fout2.close()
```

*** NOTE: Not the most efficient solution.